# Matlab coding for bandwidth interval

Tags: matlab, fft, bandwidth

I have time domain history data. Then, I convert it into FFT to get the frequency domain history data. The problem is, how to determine the bandwidth of the FFT data? Is it automatically synchronize with my time domain history data? The bandwidth of time history data is $50 Hz$-$500 Hz$.

Comment: Nothing ever happens automatically. The actual frequencies corresponding to the FFT bins depend on the sampling frequency and on the FFT lenth. If you have a length $N$ FFT and a sampling frequency $f_s$, then the bin frequencies are $f_i=i\cdot f_s/N$,  $i=0,1,\ldots,N-1$.

Comment: my sampling frequency is 512 Hz and N=6678.So to get the bandwidth of my FFT data is fi=i.512/6678,is it true?what should i value?

Comment: If your data have a maximum frequency of $500\;Hz$ then your sampling frequency should be greater than $1000\;Hz$ to avoid aliasing (i.e. lose information). Note that your (time domain) data have a certain bandwidth, regardless of the parameters of the FFT. The frequencies represented by the $N$ FFT bins can be computed by the formula in my previous comment.